# Too many roles with RBAC. Alternatives?

Tags: architecture, authorization, access-control, rbac

To represent the fact that role X can do Y on resource Z, I create a role called "role-Y:Z".
The problem is, the number of "resource"s here is ever increasing, and so are the roles.

For every resource that I create, I end up creating 4 roles.

Problem is, RBAC is too coarse-grained for my usecase.

Am I implementing RBAC the wrong way? Any idea how to avoid this role explosion? Maybe I should not use RBAC at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe I should not use RBAC at all?

You need ReBAC (Relationship Based Access Control) :)

ReBAC solutions such as those based on [Google's Zanzibar paper](https://zanzibar.academy/) are a good solution for your need of fine-grained permissions.

Some of the companies offering Fine Grained Authorization include:

- [Auth0 Fine Grained Authorization (FGA)](https://play.fga.dev/) - SaaS
- [Authzed](https://authzed.com/) - SaaS and OSS offering
- [Ory Keto](https://www.ory.sh/keto/) - OSS offering

Comment: Thanks! solves the issue perfectly!